# How to change the background color of Meld?

Tags: gtk, gnome, linux-mint, meld, cinnamon

I have Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa - Cinnamon as OS, the desktop is Gnome, and the toolkit is GTK 3.10.8 and GTK 2.24.23.
I would love to change the background of Meld to a darker color.
I followed these instructions: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Meld/DarkThemes, and the outdated technique (with a /.gtkrc-2.0 file) changed the colors what Meld use, but not the white background color. There is no variable in it for that.

I tried to create/change desktop themes as well, but I was not able to change the background of Meld (but I do not know anything about Linux Mint themes).

Any ideas, how could I change it?